# Stripe API accounts are restricted

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using php stripe API to create an account using below code,

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::create(array(
                    "type" => "custom",
                    "country" => "GB",
                    "email" => 'devetest@gmail.com',
                    'capabilities' => [
                        'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
                        'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
                    ]
        ));
```

Account is created, but it shows **restricted**  please check image ,

[image]

**Can you suggest how to clear these warnings using php Stripe API (without using stripe dashboard)**, am i missing anything im new to stripe API i checked Stripe API docs but cannot solve this one.

Comment: i create multiple accounts dynamically from site, so i cannot set all these values through dashboard for all acounts

Comment: Okay, had a quick look at the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create) which shows you can specify `business_type` which would sort the first message. Click on the second edit button to see what data is required that are missing. There also appears to be parameters for `external_accounts` that include bank accounts which probably sorts the third warning.

Comment: when i add 'business_type'=>'company' to above account api array, it gives error "Received unknown parameter: business_type"

Comment: You shouldn't get that error, it's part of the API : https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-business_type Are you perhaps using an old API version? This whole API was changed a lot in https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-02-19 so you really want to be using the latest version or it will be really hard to follow the docs.

Comment: im using stripe from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php, i think it is latest version

Comment: The version of the PHP library is not relevant to this point — it's the API version of your account that determines how the requests are processed : https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API object has a `requirements` field which describes exactly what information is needed. You provide it by calling the Account Update API. It's described in detail at
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api  . e.g. you might have a `requirements` field like this :

```
requirements: {
    current_deadline: null,
    currently_due: [
      "business_profile.mcc",
      "business_profile.url",
      "business_type",
      "external_account",
      "relationship.representative",
      "tos_acceptance.date",
      "tos_acceptance.ip"
    ],
    disabled_reason: "requirements.past_due",
    errors: [],
    eventually_due: [
      "business_profile.mcc",
      "business_profile.url",
      "business_type",
      "external_account",
      "relationship.representative",
      "tos_acceptance.date",
      "tos_acceptance.ip"
    ],
    past_due: [
      "business_profile.mcc",
      "business_profile.url",
      "business_type",
      "external_account",
      "relationship.representative",
      "tos_acceptance.date",
      "tos_acceptance.ip"
    ],
    pending_verification: []
  },
```

So for example you would clear some of these(let's take the example of "business_profile.mcc" by calling Accounts Update like this

```
\Stripe\Account::update($account->id, array(
  "business_profile" => array(
      "mcc" => "5942" // https://stripe.com/docs/connect/setting-mcc#list
    )
))
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-business_profile

---

Overall unless you specifically intend to white-label the account onboarding and KYC information collection yourself, it's **much** easier to either integrate [Express accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts)(where Stripe collects the information for you), or to use [Connect Onboarding](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding) for Custom accounts, where you just pass in an account ID and Stripe gives you a link to a page that the account holder can visit to provide any required info.

Comment: @karlleko i need clarification, say i own a shop if customer purchase 10 rupees item,i want to take 8 rupee and sent 2 rupee to another stripe account (i have their account id), how to do this in stripe API , before i used **charge API** (to get 10 rupee) and **destination attribute**  to send (2 rupee) to another account, how to do this now, since destination is deprecated, can you provide example

Comment: Destination charging as a concept is not deprecated. There's docs on doing exactly that at https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges . You'd use the `transfer_data` parameters on a PaymentIntent as described there.

Comment: @karlleko i used connect onboarding as you suggest, i manged to remove multiple warnings, still i got payout error "Add a bank account or debit card to enable payouts.",  i have to get bank details from shop owner ? is it mandatory ? , because i already got card details (token, carid)